# PostGIS Select by Distance

Tags: postgis, sql

How can I make a query that selects all the points within 10 miles of a table of polygons?

It should be a simple select by location with a buffer of 10 miles.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.name, Table1.geom
FROM            Table1
CROSS JOIN      Table2
WHERE           ST_DWithin(Table1.geom, Table2.geom, (5280 * 10))
```